Would a stream cipher gain any benefit from a more complicated function than XOR?
In a stream cipher, the keystream is usually XORed with the plaintext, which is a 1-bit key-dependent bijective operation (ie, if the key bit is 0, 0->0 and 1->1, whereas if it is 1, 0->1 and 1->0). I have seen, eg, bytewise addition discussed here (Can I safely replace XOR with ADD in a stream cipher?) as having minimal security benefit ("If your stream cipher is so broken that this makes a difference, run." – CodesInChaos) and sounds like it would still be nearly as vulnerable to a malleability attack or keystream-reuse attack, but what about a more non-linear bijective function?
EDIT: This is a question about a hypothetical science-fiction encryption scheme and whether it could have advantages in principle, not about why this has not heretofore been done in real life.
This is also not a question about whether XOR is "good enough" as long as the cryptosystem is always properly implemented and used (which I admit it is), but about whether this scheme fixes known vulnerabilities that XOR has when a cryptosystem is, as inevitably happens, sometimes not properly implemented and used.
END EDIT
For example, multiplication mod 257 or 65537 (with the all-0s value taken as -1 as in IDEA), where 8/16 bits of plaintext is turned into 8/16 bits of ciphertext dependent on 8/16 bits of keystream?
Would that get rid of malleability or would it replace it with multiplicative malleability? And would it still be trivial to break with a reused keystream?
EDIT: Okay, I think this one is a bust on further reflection. Instead of P1 XOR P2, you get P1*(P2^-1), which I assume is almost as easy to break (P1 and P2 being the two plaintexts encrypted with the same key), and the malleability becomes multiplying the ciphertext by Pa*(P1^-1) to get P1K1Pa*(P1^-1) = Pa*K1 (where P1 is the original plaintext and Pa is the attacker's desired decryption). And I think this applies to any commutative arithmetic function. END EDIT
Or, more generally, an S-box-like construction where n bits of keystream select between 2^n bijective n-bit transforms (like the DES S-boxes where each row was required to be bijective, per criterion S-3 here)?
Does that get rid of the malleability attack entirely, as long as the box is well-designed? And would it make the key-reuse attack harder?
(I am assuming that the box contents are known to the attacker and all of the security is in the keystream bits)
And would either idea introduce any obvious vulnerabilities?
(This question concerns science fiction I am writing, so you can assume it's implemented without side-channel attacks)
EDIT: Also assume that it can be implemented very cheaply in time (hardware/gate count is of secondary importance; envisage military applications by a nation that can mass-produce and custom-design VLSI chips). On purpose-built hardware, an entire AES round, including both of the arithmetical functions, can be done in 10 cycles (or possibly the whole AES encryption, it isn't clear), so assume 5 clock cycles at most, 1 cycle if it's implemented as a hardcoded lookup table (or pair of tables, 1 for encryption, 1 for decryption). The reference cipher I am using for performance is Trivium, which is parallelisable to 64 bits per clock cycle, meaning 16 copies of a four-bit transform unit, 8 copies of an 8-bit unit, etc if it costs 1 cycle per transform or the transform can be efficiently pipelined. END EDIT

Not complete, so probably not an answer, but if the message has structure then it will still show, especially when the size of the message is (much) larger than the "block size" of the operation that is performed in the scheme. Similarly, changes to parts of the ciphertext will only affect those blocks that are affected. Bigger issues may also exist, but these two properties will destroy the semantic security that is assumed.

@MaartenBodewes
Does this only apply to the case where keys are reused? Because this is already a huge problem with stream ciphers. PS Sorry for any breaches of comment etiquette, first-time commenter

Malleability is not just a problem if stream ciphers are used but also if a fully secure OTP is used. An OTP doesn't provide message integrity or authenticity, and the constructions you've indicated may make it harder to flip specific bits in the plaintext, but it doesn't disallow changes to take place (at less specific locations). This may also allow for side channel attacks that can hurt message confidentiality. As for finding patterns, yes that requires an identical key stream or, in the case of stream ciphers, an identical key.

Possibly dupe of this Perfect Secrecy other than One-time Pad and this What are the correct order of operations for One Time Pad Cipher?

I have looked at both, and the first is not relevant, although it mentions What operations provide perfect secrecy other than modulo addition, which overlaps but is less detailed (in particular my question asks about advantages and disadvantages compared to XOR); the second partially overlaps my question but is mostly concerned with pen-and-paper ciphers and again is less detailed. I can add 'one-time-pad' to the tags if the mods ask, though.

I think that the most generic mathematical combiner of key and plaintext in a character preserving manner would be a quasi-group, this is similar to a group, but does not necessarily have associativity or identity. We'd the latin square (bijective) property in order to uniquely decrypt, and to preserve character sets.
Now, groups allow malleability, for if a character were encoded $c_i=p_i*k_i$, we could swap for an encryption of $p_i'$ with the cipher character $c'_i=p'_i*(p_i^{-1}*c_i)=p'_i*k_i$. Attacks for exploiting key reuse would be similarly possible.
For quasi-groups, the non-associative property means the above does not necessarily work, because it is not necessarily true that $p_i^{-1}*(p_i*k_i)=(p_i^{-1}*p_i)*k_i$ (indeed the inverses are not defined in the absence of an identity). However, for small sets of character sizes, one could have the quasi-group operation written as a look up table; identify $k_i$ given $p_i*k_i$ and the look up table and then compute $p'_i*k_i$. For larger character set sizes, I'm not sure how one might implement decryption based on the non-associative structure.

Quasigroups don't have inverses, but they still have (left and right) division: $c_i = p_i \cdot k_i$ still implies $p_i = c_i \mathbin/ k_i$ and $k_i = p_i \mathbin\backslash c_i$. In particular, to change $p_i$ into $p'_i$, you can just replace $c_i$ with $c'_i = p'_i \cdot k_i = p'_i \cdot (p_i \mathbin\backslash c_i)$. So quasigroups are just as malleable as groups. (Of course, arbitrary quasigroups generally don't have any "nice" algorithm for either multiplication or division. But neither do arbitrary groups.)

In hindsight, my malleability question sounds stupid given that most versions imply known/guessed plaintext. But would it help with the unknown-plaintext key-reuse problem? In XOR and modulo addition, which are commutative and associative, C1-C2 = P1+K-P2-K reduces to the trivial-for-ascii P1-P2 and K can be recovered after. In the quasigroup case, C1C2 = (P1K)(P2K), C1/C2 = (P1K)/(P2K), and C1\C2 = (P1K)(P2K). Would an attacker need to figure out K to get to P1 or P2, or does one of these equations have a reduction I am just not seeing?

If there is nothing known about the plaintext then the plaintext must be fully random. That's of very limited scope, especially since you'd need as many bits in the OTP as what you are encrypting. We need ciphers to be secure even if part of the plaintext is known.

Sorry, I am not a professional cryptographer, so here is what I was trying to say: The examples from Applied Cryptography of a malleability attack, iirc, are to substitute your account details into a recipient's account field in a money transfer (block cipher in ECB) or to change the amount from 100 dollars into 1000000 dollars (stream cipher), in both cases by knowing in some detail the structure of the message; what I meant by unknown-plaintext is, eg, "it's a HTTPS packet, so it's probably UTF-8-coded HTML but it could be part of a PNG file", that level of unknown.

In short, no.
Consider a stream cipher to be an analogue of a one-time pad. You're combining a signal (the plaintext) with noise, and using the information-theoretic value of the noise to blur the signal to indecipherability. The difference formally is that you're seeding a PRNG with a key, and you can even think of this as a form of compression. You're trading easy transport of your randomness for some loss of searching.
If we consider a character-level mix, addition works fine. Your plaintext is an A, the stream character is E; A is 1, E is 5, the result is 6 or F, and poof, Alice is your auntie.
Most stream ciphers actually work at the bit level -- LFSRs literally work that way, and it's trivial to see how counter-mode works at a bit level. We typically work on groups of eight bits, but that's not necessary. You can encrypt nine bits with a stream cipher. While we're at it, I'll note that most hash functions also work at the bit-level. It was in fact one of the requirements of SHA-3. (Full disclosure: I was one of the Skein/Threefish authors.) This is the difference between a stream cipher and a block cipher, that a stream cipher (usually) works on bits, and block ciphers work on chunks of bits we call blocks. You could have a block cipher of seventeen bits if you wanted. (And yes, further in the minutia, that means that you can consider some stream ciphers like RC4 to be an eight-bit block cipher with a built-in chaining mode. It all depends on which lenses you like to view the world through.)
At the bit level, XOR is addition. Even in blocks of bits (like words), an XOR is addition without carry of columns of bits. You can view a generic XOR of a word size to be a whole bunch of bit additions done in parallel.
You can make a more complex function than XOR that satisfies our requirement -- that it preserves the infomation-theoretic mixing a signal and noise. You just aren't going to be better in the sense of more secure, and you're going to be slower. Or not faster, anyway. Typically, both add and xor take the same amount of time, a single clock (or microclock) cycle.
So there's no benefit because xor is good enough; on an information theoretic level you can't get better; xor works on single bits as well as groups; thus at the bit-level, xor and add are the same (otherwise it's an alternative); and you aren't going to find something else that's faster.

Except if two messages are encrypted with the same key, in which case it reduces to a running-key cipher (ie trivial if both messages are recognisable text) even if I can assume the key is a one-time pad. C1+C2 = (P1+K)+(P2+K) = P1+P2 (or C1-C2 = (P1+K)-(P2+K) = P1-P2), xor/add are commutative and associative. My question is, is there something that doesn't reduce to that? IE, is there an operation '' with an inverse '/' where C1/C2 = (P1K)/(P2*K) does not reduce to P1/P2 and an attacker must figure out K to get P1 or P2? Can the attack be made even slightly less trivial?

If I may be pedantic, the question asks if there's a benefit. No, there's no benefit. There are trivial alternate constructions, and XOR has the benefit that it's typically really, really cheap, even in that it might be zero-cost on some CPUs. Even on an Intel CPU, it's usually 1/3 of a clock cycle. That's why ARX constructions are so powerful.

If I may be pedantic, I asked if there was a benefit compared to XOR specifically in the event of "malleability attack or keystream-reuse attack". Your answer answered neither. You instead answered the question of why XOR has heretofore been used, and that XOR is good enough if I can ignore these attacks and assume that the cryptosystem is never misused. You never even mentioned malleability or keystream reuse (even to explain that the proper term is "related-key attack"), let alone explained why there would not be a benefit in those situations.
